# Getting status code 0 in ajax call to cross site Perl CGI function

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl

The Perl CGI script is being called; I can see the debug logs getting getting the parameters and executing.

The issue is returning the results, the status code is always 0, with responseText empty.

Have tried various header options etc, with no luck, any help would be much appreciated.

*Perl CGI handler*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

my $q = new CGI;
my %data;

open my $FH, '>', 'outfile';

if ( my $number = $q->param('number') ){
    if ( $number =~ /^\d+$/ ) {
            $data{result} = $number % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even';
    } else {
            $data{result} = 'Not a number';
    }

    my $jret = to_json(\%data);
    print $FH Dumper($jret);
    close $FH;

    print $q->header('application/json');
    print to_json(\%data);
}
```

*HTML code*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>[% title %]</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">      </script>
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='result'></div>Enter number:
    <form>
    <input type='text' id='number'> 
    <button onclick='test_number();'>Test</button>

    <script>
        function test_number()
        {
            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '/cgi-bin/simple.cgi',
                    data: {
                            'number': $('#number').val()
                    },
                    success: function(data, textStatus ){
                       alert('request successful');
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                        msg =  'Request Status: ' + jqXHR.status + ' Status Text: ' + jqXHR.statusText + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText;
                        alert(msg);
                    }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show more of your Perl code. Specifically if there are any other `print` statements above the ones you've shown.

Comment: If the status is `0` then there is usually a useful error message displayed on the Console in the browser's Developer Tools. You need to look there.

Comment: Your Perl code looks fine. There is nothing wrong with it. Look at the request in your Developer Tools too. It might be that your `POST` request is not actually submitting a form, but that the JS object  in `data` is serialized to JSON and submitted as the body of the request instead of converted to formdata. If that's the case, CGI.pm cannot read it and `$q->param('number')` will be false, thus your program will never print anything and just exit. If there's no output, you can't see anything.

Comment: Is that HTML code enough to constitute a [mcve]? If there was a `<form>` element then that would make a significant difference.

Comment: @simbabque — `data` doesn't have a JSON data structure. Just a regular JS one. jQuery will serialize it using the normal form data encoding.

Comment: I've tried it with and without the a form, same result, statusText = 'error', status = 0. 

The CGI script is getting the data from the web client, to be sure I just tested the same instance of the CGI script with an Android client running native code, it worked perfectly including able to read the response.

The web client can send the data correctly, the CGI can process that data just fine, seems to be sending it back alright too as I'm able to view the return JSON object populated in the android client. 

I'll post the complete HTML code here.

Comment: I'm running this CGI code on an apache EC2 instance I set up, could there be some issue with the server setup? Running multiple vhosts, with a single common cgi-bin directory. This HTML code is hosted within one of the vhosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run the JavaScript function when a submit button in a form is clicked.

This:

1. Sends the Ajax request
2. Unloads the current page
3. Submits the form
4. Loads a new page

---

## Quick hack

Use `type="button"` for your button element so it is not a submit button

## Proper solution

1. Set `<form action="/cgi-bin/simple.cgi"` so the form submits the correct place
2. Add `name="number"` to the input so it is included in the regular form data
3. Add a means to distinguish between a form submission and an Ajax request such as a hidden input
4. Update the script so if it gets the form submission it renders an appropriate HTML document instead of JSON
5. Remove the `onclick` attribute and bind a proper event handler with JavaScript (which prevents the default behaviour of the form submission if JS successfully runs)

Such:

```
function test_number(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/cgi-bin/simple.cgi',
        data: {
            'number': $('#number').val()
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            alert('request successful');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            msg = 'Request Status: ' + jqXHR.status + ' Status Text: ' + jqXHR.statusText + ' ' + jqXHR.responseText;
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
}

document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", test_number);
```